# RSpec and FactoryGirl - building unique assocations?

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

A `feedback` model requires an `account` to exist. Each `account` has a unique :uuid that is validated in the model: `validates :uuid, presence: true, uniqueness: true`

I was using rspec to test the feedback model and kept getting `Uuid has already been taken` errors whenever I built a `feedback` object because feedback was building an associated `account`

## spec/models/feedback_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Feedback do
  it "is valid with a message" do
    expect(build(:feedback)).to be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a message" do
    expect(build(:feedback, message: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:message)
  end

  it "is invalid without an associated account" do
    expect(build(:feedback, account: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:account)
  end
end
```

## spec/factories/feedbacks.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :feedback do
    association :account
    message Faker::Lorem.paragraphs
  end
end
```

## spec/factories/accounts.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    # uuid SecureRandom.uuid # THIS LINE WILL NOT WORK
    sequence(:uuid) { |n| n } # THIS LINE WORKS
    active true
  end
end
```

As you can see from the accounts.rb factory, the line `uuid SecureRandom.uuid` always seemed to return the same UUID when I created an `account` in the `feedback_spec.rb` file.

I'm wondering, does FactoryGirl only build the account object ONCE and then re-use it for each individual test?  I was expecting a unique UUID for each account object but that obviously didn't work.  However, when I switched to using the `sequence(:uuid) { |n| n }` line it worked just fine.

Trying to understand how FactoryGirl creates these objects for testing.  It's obviously not the way I was thinking.  My tests now run properly, but things that I don't understand will eventually come back to haunt me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    uuid { SecureRandom.uuid }
    active true
  end
end
```

This will evaluate `SecureRandom.uuid` whenever an account factory is invoked instead of just the once when FactoryGirl defines it's factories.

**Edit:**

See [Factory Girl Lazy Attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes) for more info.

Comment: I just found that after I re-read a chapter on RSpec. Those little curly braces are very sneaky! This does indeed solve the problem just as you said.

Comment: Bitten by Rspec and lazy-loading again!